# Why does httpd seem to use a different version of python with the same executable?

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, apache-2.4, virtualenv

I am running Apache httpd 2.4.4 on a RedHat 5 machine. I am using Django and running through mod_wsgi. I have Python 2.4.3 installed in /usr/bin and Python 2.7.6 installed in /usr/local/bin and I want to use 2.7.6. I build the 2.7.6 from source and also built mod_wsgi-3.4.

I have created a virtualenv using 2.7.6 and from a command shell, python -V tells me it's using 2.7.6 (after doing a `. virtpy/bin/activate`). Running `import sys; sys.version` shows me 2.7.6 as well, and `sys.executable` shows me `/www/sqla/virtpy/bin/python`.

When I run it from httpd, I get problems loading libraries and when I look at `sys.version`, I see **2.7.3**. The weird thing is that `sys.executable` still shows me `/www/sqla/virtpy/bin/python`, *exactly the same one as I see from the command shell*.

Specifically, when python tries to load _socket, I see this error from httpd:

`ImportError: /www/sqla/virtpy/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_socket.so: undefined symbol: _PyInt_AsInt`

If I try to import _socket from a command shell, no problem. I have `. /www/sqla/virtpy/bin/activate` in my /etc/sysconfig/httpd and have restarted Apache with that change.

How can the same executable give different versions of python? How can I convince it to use the right one?

Comment: Just to clarify, you built mod_wsgi in the virtualenv, using 2.7.6, correct?

Comment: @tfitzgerald Yes, I made sure of that. In fact I rebuilt it again (clean) just to make sure.

Comment: Ok.  What does your wsgi app / file look like?  Might need to use `site.addsitedir` to point to the 2.7.6 site packages in your virtualenv.

Comment: But by the time my wsgi app is invoked, python is already running, and is using the wrong version.

Answer (score 4):

Use the checks documented in the mod_wsgi documentation to validate that how your mod_wsgi was compiled is correct:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Shared_Library

Ensure that when doing this check that LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set. Provide the output from ldd.

Also indicate whether you also have any Python 2.7 installation under /usr in addition to the one under /usr/local and specifically whether there is a Python 2.7 shared library under /usr/lib anywhere.

If you have used WSGIPythonHome directive in Apache configuration, say what you have set it to.

Comment: The ldd output for mod_wsgi.so includes "libpython2.7.so.1.0". If I run it with LD_LIBRARY_THREAD unset, it says "=> not found". The only libpython* under /usr/lib is /usr/lib/python2.4/config/libpython2.4.a. No WSGIPythonHome is set.

Comment: But where is the libpython2.7.so it finds located? That it can't be found without LD_LIBRARY_PATH being set is not good and means you would have to be setting that in environment of Apache. You should really set LD_RUN_PATH at compile time so directory it is in is embedded in mod_wsgi.so so can find it.

Comment: OK, done. I did "LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib make" (clean) and "sudo make install". Doing an ldd on the resulting library (with LD_LIBRARY_PATH empty) shows "libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00002b01f2199000)". But I still see the same result.

(Note that in the comment above, I meant LD_LIBRARY_PATH, not LD_LIBRARY_THREAD).

Comment: The only other thing can think of is that have seen this issue when the Python virtual environment was created off one Python patch level and then the main Python installation was upgraded without recreating the virtual environment.